# Opening/Mounting a .img file

Tags: macos, terminal, mount

How would I do this?

I have attempted double clicking on it (obviously) and I get an error of it saying that its not recognized.

My second though was using Disk Utility (the app) to try and change it from an img to an iso. The same error appeared saying that it was not recognized.

My last idea was to do some research on mounting from the terminal. The command that I used was

```
mount -o loop userdata.img /mnt/testcache
```

The result of that was:

```
mount: You must specify a filesystem type with -t.
```

After that I just ran out of idea and ran out of search queries to try.

Comment: Are you sure it's not corrupt? If you downloaded it, does it have the exact same size as the original?

Comment: Yes it has the exact size. I made sure to double check it before posting here.

Comment: Do you have a checksum for the img file? Size doesn't say anything about the content being correct

Comment: Not all image files are mountable, especially if they are RAW images. Can you give a link to the image?

Answer (score 2):

Provided the image is a correct image file supported by OS X the correct command to mount would be `hdiutil attach imagename`.

Not all files ending with `.img` are disk images at all, let alone supported by OS X. You can try to use `file image name` to see what this file actually might be, but even for valid classic image files this may just result in *data* as an answer.

It would be most helpful to know how or using which software this image was created.